# How to ease upset stomach when hungover?

Tags: comfort

Ended up drinking a bit to much last night and have been severely hung over for the past 3 hours.  I can deal with the headache (sunglasses, OTC pain meds, hot shower, etc) but this upset stomach is just killing me.  I'm afraid to eat anything because I know I'll just puke it right back up.  Any life hacks for easing an upset stomach, specifically during a hangover?

Comment: Answer: Don't drink so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason people get stomach aches when they are hungover is because drinking a lot of alcohol raises the level of acid in your stomach. To cure this, you need to soak up the acid. Eating something dry like plain toast (nothing on it) or saltine crackers. I know you don't want to eat anything because you don't want to vomit, but these foods are not tough on your stomach, so you shouldn't have to throw up. If you do throw up, it's not all bad because vomiting can help you cure your stomach ache. Also, to avoid a hangover, try to drink lots of water before you go to sleep the night you were drinking.

Comment: cool, thank you! just ate some toast and definitely helped and i didn't puke :)

Comment: There are more effective ways to soak up excess stomach acid than dry foods - you want to avoid acidic foods such as most fruit, sauces and sodas, but a more direct approach would be something alkaline - e.g. a Rennie tablet or a spoonful of baking soda; or alternatively fatty foods e.g. a slice of bread with lots of butter and cheese on top.

Comment: @Peteris Too much fat will form lumps in your stomach that might cause other discomfort, so baking soda is probably better.